# center text in cell and adjust cell width

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I've got two problems which I'm currently not able to solve properly on my own and therefore I am looking for help!

1. I am looking for a way to center the text in the cells of my table. Currently I am using grid() to build my table, but haven't found a way to center the text in the generated cells.
2. The width of my cells is static, but I'd like to have it dynamically adjusting to the width of the column headline. I've tried counting characters of my headlines for each column, but unfortunatly that didnt work out in the correct way.

```
n_rows = df.shape[0]
n_cols = df.shape[1]

column_names = df.columns
i=0
for j, col in enumerate(column_names):
    text = Text(ausgabe, width=26, height=1.2, bg = "#9BC2E6")
    text.config(font=("Arial", 20))
    text.grid(row=i,column=j)
    text.insert(INSERT, col)
     
for i in range(n_rows):
    for j in range(n_cols):
        text = Text(ausgabe, width=26, height=1.2)
        text.config(font=("Arial", 20))
        text.grid(row=i+1, column=j)
        text.insert(INSERT, df.loc[i][j])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the text in a `Text` widget, you need to configure the `justify` option of a `tag` and insert the text using the `tag`:

```
text.tag_config('center', justify='center') # config a tag
text.insert(INSERT, ..., 'center') # specify the tag
```

To set the width of a column, find the width using `len()` and add `sticky='ew'` to all `.grid(...)`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
for j, col in enumerate(column_names):
    text = Text(ausgabe, width=len(col), height=1.2, bg="#9BC2E6")
    text.config(font=("Arial", 20))
    text.grid(row=0, column=j, sticky='ew') # added sticky option
    text.tag_config('center', justify='center') # config a tag
    text.insert(INSERT, col, 'center') # use the tag

for i in range(n_rows):
    for j in range(n_cols):
        value = df.loc[i][j]
        text = Text(ausgabe, width=len(str(value)), height=1.2)
        text.config(font=("Arial", 20))
        text.grid(row=i+1, column=j, sticky='ew')
        text.tag_config('center', justify='center')
        text.insert(INSERT, value, 'center')
```

Below is the result with sample data:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Iirc I did the same with the column width but it didnt work properly :(

Comment: What do you mean by *"it didn't work properly"*?  I have attached an image width different headers and cell values.

Comment: I ment that my own solution didnt work properly! But I still got an issue: the width of the first column doesnt adjust properly to the header. The first column should be "Nummer" but it only shows "Numm" in my table. I attached an image for better understanding.  <img src="https://imgur.com/a/ribFQGw.png">

Comment: @FinneX I think it is the font issue. If you use a monospaced font, it will be ok.  I think `Text` widget will calculate the *average* width of a character for the font used to set the width of the widget.  So if the width of most of the characters in a string is larger than the *average* width, the string cannot be displayed fully.

Comment: good point, thank you!